# Inconsistent UVmap when 'follow active quads'

Tags: texturing, uv

On the UVmap where the islands are double layered is where that nasty Texture inconsistency is.
I was wondering if there is a way to 1.) Unwrap 2.) Reset 3.) Follow active quads with an even Square uv map
I'm actually using 'UV squares' Add on to achieve the same effect.

I try to turn the uvmap into a single, even rectangle or square and it will layer islands unto itself creating these texture inconsistencies

How do I get an even uvmap without it layering islands and keeping all of the proper faces next to each other?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I decided instead of making the Uv fit the image, I’d just make the image fit the UV !
I exported the uv maps into photoshop and warped them.

[image]